# Get a list of webelements if condition is true

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am passing an argument. I want to get a list of web elements based on a xpath if the passed argument is true. Following is the code I use to get the list of webelements without condition and do some operations on that:

```
    @{elements}    Get Webelements    //a[.//div[@class='theme-cell-card ace']]
    @{elements_text}     Create List
    :FOR   ${element}    IN    @{elements}
    \        ${element_text}    Get Text    ${element}
    \        Append To List  ${elements_text}  ${element_text}
    [RETURN]    ${elements_text}
```

I want to write something like the following:

```
    @{elements}=    Run Keyword If     "${passed argument}"=="ace"      Get Webelements    //a[.//div[@class='theme-cell-card ace']]
```

I know it does not work. Very thankful if someone help me with a solution

Comment: So why doesn't it work, the syntax looks ok? What are you trying to achieve? I guess do something else if the argument is not equal to - but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Todor You are right, syntax is correct. I tried running again. Sometimes {elements} returns list and sometimes empty list. Probably network speed. I spent more than an hour yesterday evening :(

Comment: @Todor any way thanks :)

Comment: I added Sleep after the condition and it works

Comment: To salvage that - "Sometimes {elements} returns list and sometimes empty list." - put a `Wait Until Element Is Visible` before you get the elements (I'm almost certain that keyword works also with the multiple values in your xpath).